# How do I use the flat() method to get certain values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, flatten

I'm taking an online course which uses a bot to correct JavaScript code. The challenge is to
Create an array `a` and make so that `a.length === 2` is `true`,
`a[0].length === 1` is `true`,,
and `a.flat()` should 'print out' `['a', 'b' 'c']`

The bot output tells me that `'defines a such that a[0].length === 1 evaluates to true'`  isn't correct.

This is my code so far:

```
let a = ['a','b','c']

a.length === 2
a[0].length === 1
a.flat()
```

So far I've tried to put an array inside the array, but I can't figure out where to put the brackets, like this, but it doesn't work.

```
let a = [['a','b'],'c']

a.length === 2
a[0].length === 1
a.flat()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the following:

```js
let a = ['a', ['b', 'c']]

console.log('a.length === 2', a.length === 2)
// a.length === 2 true

console.log('a[0].length === 1', a[0].length === 1)
// a[0].length === 1 true

console.log('a.flat()', a.flat())
// a.flat() ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

The first "test" states that the length of the `a` array has to be two, hence I'll start with:

```js
let a = [ _, _ ]
```

The second "test" states that the first element of `a` must have a length of 1. Having a total of 3 elements, this brought me to:

```js
let a = [ _, [ _, _ ] ]
```

Filling the gaps, then:

```js
let a = ['a', ['b', 'c']]
```

Hope it is clearer this way :)

Comment: How does this differ from the code that the OP posted in their question? Please explain in words what the difference is.